# Laravel5.3 connecting and syncing multiple databases

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have two sites site1.dev and site2.dev pointing to the same application. What I want is connect site1.dev to one database (db1) and site2.dev to other(db2) and sync db1 to db2 . well I found out that using more than two databases is possible , but what I actually want is syncing all activites of db1 to db2 . I have also created a logs table for recording activites for create, edit and delete. 
This is the schema of the table

```
    Schema::create('sync_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('model_id')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->string('model')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->integer('action')->comment('0=>Create, 1=>Update, 2=>Delete');
        $table->text('data');
        $table->boolean('synced')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I am planning to retrieve all the unsynced data and insert the data to db2 in loop.
Is this possible ? What are the ways to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried [database replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(computing)#Database_replication) or you are trying to implement this yourself. If it is the second one please give us more information on when you want to replicate the databases and  a bit more for the setup you are expecting. for example will the databases always be on the same machine?

Comment: The databases will not always be on the same machine . db1 will be on the client machine and db2 on the cloud server, but for development purpose I want both of them on my machine for now. When the application is installed on the client machine , all activities are recorded in db1 and db2 will be updated every day at one time.

Comment: Ok so you can use https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling for the timing and tan serialize all the models that haven't been synchronized

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by recording the track of the data which is synced to the database. Like, save the last id for an employee table in the tracking table and run a cronjob everyday to check if the employee table id is greater than the tracking table foreign key (employee_id) then sync the un-synced employee data to DB2.